# Run Spark in standalone mode with Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr, elastic-map-reduce

I've a problem: I cannot run a MapReduce Spark Job written in Java in AWS enviorment EMR.
I've a maser node and 5 slaves.

What is the correct way to let Spark run the java class?

I tried with this [guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/) but it doesn't work to me.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The amazon documentation is probably better suited for EMR specific setup questions. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-spark-interactive-batch.html (specifically https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-spark-submit-step.html for batch jobs).

Comment: Spark on EMR is preconfigured for YARN.